# Only 10 newest rows inside 2D-array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, imshow

Edit: Mr. T's solution works for me, by using `np.roll` with -1 scroll lines.
I have a matplotlib raster that's displaying stacked up data based on a 2D-array that's concatenated with a 1D-array roughly every second:

```
concat = np.concatenate((concat_array, data_array), axis=0)
```

I want the concatenated 2D-array to be not longer than 10 rows, so the last 10 rows are present in the array. That's because I want the matplotlib `imshow` raster to not display more lines that are older than 10 iterations.

```
if (len(concat_array) > 10): # Returns the amount of rows
    np.delete(concat_array, np.s_[10:], 0)
```

Does `np.delete` work in this case? Or is there some other way to achieve this?

Comment: Afaik, concatenating and deleting forces numpy to reassign a new array. Why don't you use [np.roll](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) and just fill the last line with your new data? As for the animation part - how would I know without the rest of the script?

Comment: @Mr.T I don't think rolling will work, because new data is appended and the data older than 10 iterations can be omitted. Rolling is just changing the the order in which the items are stored afaik.

Comment: Instead of abc-> abcd -> bcd which creates two new arrays, you could simply roll and fill abc -> bca -> bcd.

Comment: That's actually a promising solution! I'll try that.

Comment: It looks like the rolling does not work. Before rolling, I assign the new data to concat_array[10], but the data in concat_array[0:9] does not shift down. I use np.roll(concat_array, -1, axis=0).

Comment: If you want to keep the last 10 rows, just use slicing: `arr = arr[-10:]`.  Focus on what you want to keep, not on what you want to delete.  Another thing to consider - array concatenate is slow compared to list append.  So maintaining a list of arrays might be faster.  You can still slice a list as I suggested.